# Not able to mock Integer wrapper class using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying unit test a function which returns a integer value after doing a delete operation in database. This function returns a integer value of 0 or 1 depending on the failure or success. I am finding it hard to mock this. Here is the code snippet:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
public class SampleUnitTest {

    @Mock private DeleteService mockService;

    @InjectMocks private DeleteResource deleteResource;

@Test
    public void shouldDelete() throws Exception {
        initRequest();

        //getting error in this line
        Integer response = mock(Integer.class);

        //this is the function which performs the actual delete in db and I am trying to mock this and return 1 or 0
        when(mockService.deleteDataFromDb(any(),any())).thenReturn(response);

  ......

    }
}
```

Error I am getting:

> ```java
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.Integer
> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
> - Cannot mock wrapper types, String.class or Class.class
> ```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to return 1 or 0, then just make it return 1 or 0.  No mocking required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I don’t mock it , it will call the function and giving me null pointer exception

Comment: No it won't.  You write `when(mockService.deleteDataFromDb(any(),any())).thenReturn(1);`.  That stubs away your method call, but controls what gets returned from it.

Comment: It is never appropriate to mock an `Integer` object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's not only inappropriate, According to the exception message it's even impossible. :)